# C++ map<string, vector<pair<string, string> > > : adding a mapping to an empty vector?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, vector, containers

I'm very new to C++ container templates.  I have a collection of **records**.  Each record has a unique name, and a list of field/value pairs.  The records will be accessed by name.  The order of the field/value pairs is important.  Hence I've designed it as follows:

```
typedef string      Typecode;
typedef string      Fieldname;
typedef string      Fieldvalue;
typedef vector<pair<Fieldname, Fieldvalue> >  Field_value_pairs;
typedef map<Typecode, Field_value_pairs>      Record_map;

Record_map          records;
```

I want to define a method **add_record(Typecode)** that will add an entry to **records** with a key of type Typecode and an empty Field_value_pairs vector.  (At some point later on I will add some or all of the field/value pairs.)  But I can't seem to figure out what map<> and vector<> methods to use.

I think I want to use **operator=**, as in `records["foo_record"] =`.  But what should I assign as the value, to create an "empty vector of pairs"?

Comment: assign it `Field_value_pairs();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign as:

```
records["foo_record"] = vector<pair<Fieldname, FieldValue> >();
```

std::vector's default constructor will create an empty vector, and then you can add new values to it using

```
records["foo_record"].push_back(pair<Fieldname, FieldValue>("name", "value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Default construct a `Field_value_pairs` object and assign it to the new map entry.

```
void add_record( Record_map& records, Typecode const& code )
{
    records[code] = Field_value_pairs();
}
```

Beware that this will overwrite any existing entry for that `Typecode`. If you want to conditionally add a `Typecode` only if one doesn't already exist, use `map::find` to determine whether the entry exists.

```
void add_record( Record_map& records, Typecode const& code )
{
    if( records.find( code ) == records.end() ) {
        records[code] = Field_value_pairs();
    } else {
        // entry exists, do something else
    }
}
```